# Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop Sharing resolution

Tags: 11.10, resolution, vnc, remote, vino

I have 11.10 running on a Netbook with Unity2D @ 1024x600 resolution.  I VNC into my Ubuntu Netbook from Win7 @ 1920x1200.  Is there a way make Desktop Sharing on 11.10 run at a resolution higher than the hardware resolution?  I am not too worried about speed/lag.  1440x900 would be perfect.  I like to keep my machine as clean as possible, I could add eg. vnc4server but I'd prefer not to do that.  I have looked for but cannot find an appropriate vino-server config file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may change the monitor resolution on Ubuntu desktop higher than the local system display hardware can support for remote desktop access with the following steps:

Perform a check for the local system display name/identification used by Ubuntu using xrandr command.

```
xrandr
```

Create a new mode say “1440x900”. The setting parameters can be obtained from a windows system with the appropriate display installed, using EDID Reader e.g. ‘Monitor Asset Manager - moninfo.exe’

```
sudo xrandr –newmode "1440x900" 106.500 1440 1520 1672 1904 900 903 909 934 +hsync +vsync
```

Then add the new mode to the VGA-0 i.e. the name of the system monitor.

```
sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1440x900
```

On the remote desktop, issue the following command to change the desktop resolution

```
sudo xrandr --output VGA-0  --mode 1440x900
```